# glpk issue when using a variable to limit a sumation

Tags: glpk

I am having some issues when trying to define the following constraint:

```
s.t. accumulative_times{i in JOBS}: actimes[i] = sum{j in  PLACES,k in JOBS : j <= placing[i] } t[k,j]*time[k];
```

with the following definitions:

```
param n >=0;

set JOBS  := 1..n;
set PLACES := 1..n;


param d{PLACES};
param time{JOBS};
var t{i in PLACES,j in JOBS} binary;
var delay{i in JOBS} integer;
var placing{i in JOBS} integer;
var actimes{i in JOBS} integer;

s.t. constraint1{i in PLACES} :sum{j in JOBS} t[i,j] =1;


s.t. constraint2{j in JOBS} :sum{i in PLACES} t[i,j] =1;

s.t. place_cons{i in JOBS}: placing[i] = sum{j in PLACES} j*t[j,i];


s.t. accumulative_times{i in JOBS}: actimes[i] = sum{j in  PLACES,k in JOBS : j <= placing[i] } t[k,j]*time[k];
```

I am trying to calculate the total time a task will wait until be conclude.
Someone know what I am doin'g wrong or some other way to define this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

GLPK can only solve linear problems. Therefore the coefficients of the LP cannot depend on a variable.

Instead of your integer variable placing you could use an array of binary variables that indicates job i is waiting in period j.

Or you use binaries indicating that job i is processed in period j and further non-integer variables depending on these binaries.